# Sorting files in linux

Tags: linux, file, sorting

I want to sort a file in linux. `sort -n file.txt` doesn't work!

The file that i want to sort is this. Between each number there are 3 space. I want to sort according to the last number of each row.

```
20.799999 13.760000   -15.200000  -10.560000  20.000000  -5.00000  
3.90001   -9.7705E-02  -0.95687      -0.167488      0.12431613   -0.7140
```

How do I sort the file?

Comment: Did you read *carefully* the documentation of [sort(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)? If it is not enough, you could code your own sorting program (e.g. using C++ [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort))

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-g` option to make numbers with exponentials work. To sort on the 6th field, use `-k6`. Put together, `sort -g -k6 file.txt`.

Comment: it,s working, THANK U!